# Updating a block's edit / save without reinventing the wheel

Tags: block-editor

## TL;DR

How can I change the `edit` and `save` result of a core block without having to re-implement most of its functionality in my own code?

## Question

I'm familiar with the [block filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/) and am already able to use them to add attributes or new InspectorControls. However, it bugs me that it seems I cannot update the JSX/HTML of the edit/save without having to overwrite the whole block.

Imagine the following scenario: I want to add a setting to the `core/button` block to append an icon after the text. So the final HTML **should not** be

```
<div class="wp-block-button">
    <a class="wp-block-button__link">Hello World</a>
</div>
```

but instead the **desired result** is

```
<div class="wp-block-button">
    <a class="wp-block-button__link">Hello World</a>
    <span class="wp-block-button__icon">X</span>
</div>
```

For `save` I could probably use `wp.element.cloneElement` to add my own element as an additional child.

But what for `edit`? My current understanding is that as long as the block does not use [SlotFills](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/slotfills/), I don't really have an option.

In the usual setup like this

```
const withInspectorControls = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
  return (props) => {
    const { name, attributes, setAttributes } = props
    if (name !== 'core/button') {
      return <BlockEdit {...props} />
    }

    const { showIcon } = attributes

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <BlockEdit {...props} />
        <InspectorControls>
          <PanelBody title={__('Show Icon?', 'my-plugin')}>
            <ToggleControl
              label={__('Show Icon?', 'my-plugin')}
              checked={showIcon}
              onChange={(showIcon) => setAttributes({ showIcon })}
            />
          </PanelBody>
        </InspectorControls>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
})

addFilter('editor.BlockEdit', 'my-plugin/add-icon-inspector', withInspectorControls)
```

I could drop the `<BlockEdit {..props} />` part and re-implement the button. But looking at [the source of the edit](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/%40wordpress/block-library%402.27.2/packages/block-library/src/button/edit.js) I know that I'd have to either re-implement the complete `ButtonEdit` method, which I would like to avoid.

Various guides as well as other answers on this stack imply that it makes more sense to create a new block (and de-register/blacklist the core one), is this still valid for 2021?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have to do it with a span tag? Would CSS not work?  Adding the icon attribute is aa different question from using/displaying the attribute to add the markup, by combining both questions into a single question you severely reduce your chances of an answer ( e.g. I know how to add an option to add set and save an additional attribute, but I don't know how to modify the edit/save component to add the new tag )

Comment: Also, buttons can have inline images, so the solution to your problem might actually be unrelated to anything you've mentioned, e.g. I can see a way to do this purely by registering a richtext format

Comment: @TomJNowell This is just an example, I tried to minimize it as much as possible. The goal is to change the actual DOM/markup, not just add classes/data-attributes. Tomorrow I can try to rephrase it to "How can I change the rendered markup in the edit?" (afaik `cloneElement` gives me enough freedoms for save).

Comment: I believe the example you want can be done by registering a format, complete with the span tag

Comment: @TomJNowell I haven't read about formats yet, thanks for that pointer. But it seems that it would be a bit hacky/misuse to use a format for this, or not?

Comment: No, I'd actually argue that modifying the edit component is hacky, and may actually be a dead end that causes block validation to fail

Comment: unfortunately, javascript block actions and filters are almost not used in blocks, while they could be used, similarly to PHP. As a proof of concept, I added filter to one of my own blocks to change markup and it does work. I spoke with one person who is one of main contributors to Gutenberg project and she did not now why they did not use actions and filters in the block code. I just hope this will be fixed in the future, and you can open that issue if it already isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with the format API, for example, this code from the handbook will add a `<samp>` tag around text:

```js
import { registerFormatType, toggleFormat } from '@wordpress/rich-text';
import { RichTextToolbarButton } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
 
const MyCustomButton = ( props ) => {
    return <RichTextToolbarButton
        icon='editor-code'
        title='Sample output'
        onClick={ () => {
            props.onChange( toggleFormat(
                props.value,
                { type: 'my-custom-format/sample-output' }
            ) );
        } }
        isActive={ props.isActive }
    />;
};
 
registerFormatType(
    'my-custom-format/sample-output', {
        title: 'Sample output',
        tagName: 'samp',
        className: null,
        edit: MyCustomButton,
    }
);
```

Likewise, you can use the same tricks the image format uses to insert a single element without it wrapping text:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/format-library/src/image/index.js

Specifically, it imports `insertObject`:

```
                            insertObject( value, {
                                type: name,
                                attributes: {
                                    className: `wp-image-${ id }`,
                                    style: `width: ${ Math.min(
                                        imgWidth,
                                        150
                                    ) }px;`,
                                    url,
                                    alt,
                                },
                            } )
```

Where `name` is the name of the format that was registered. The result is an inline `<img>` tag.